# GroupPrincipal throws argument exception

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a static method that validate, if the user is in AdGroup or not.
The method looks like:

```
 public static bool IsUserInAdGroup(string groupname, string name)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(groupname) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            {
                return false;
            }

            // create your domain context
            var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Configuration.GetValue("ad"));

            // find the group in question
            var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, groupname);

            // find a user
            var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, name);



            if (user != null && group != null)
            {
                if (user.IsMemberOf(group))
                {
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }

            return false;

        }
```

I wrote a UnitTest for that method and it works fine. But when I call the method from WPF application, I've got an exception:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where does the exception throw? At which line? If it's at `GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity`, it'd seem like the group name you're passing isn't correct...

Comment: The exception was throw at `GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity`. The group name should be correct, because I make a unit test and it passed.

Comment: I see. I'd still compare the string that's being used in the test and the one used in runtime, just to be sure. `FindByIdentity` seems to work well with built-in system names but not with custom.